# How to write %install in .py file

Tags: python, import

I use the code
%install package ver. which output is [Conda package activated] in my code, but i want to put my function in .py file.
when i do that, error of saying this %install part is

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want to know, how should  I put that in a .py file

I tried to create .py file without that code, but it does not work

Comment: Pure Python will run faster and be more portable, and so it is best. However, as you've found converting can bring headaches. In case you didn't know, you can also make IPython scripts ending in `.ipy` and those can include many of the IPython/Jupyter magic lines. You can run them with IPython on the command line similarly to how'd you run Python script, such as `ipython my_script.ipy`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like `%install` is what is called a "magic command" or "Magic", which is a special code snippet some environments (e.g. Jupyter) provide to run commands outside of python. For example, [here is the list of magics available in IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

As they are not part of the standard python interpreter, you cannot use them in normal .py scripts.

Instead, you can call for example `conda install <package>` or `pip install <package>` from the command line (your OS command line, not an interactive python shell!) to install the package.

As a workaround, you *can* call the command line from inside python:

```
import os
os.system("conda install <package> -y")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried for example with sklean 1.2.1  os.system("conda install sklearn-1.1.2 -y") but when run this the output shows like -2 ...I was wondering how to do this